# Why beaucoup du thé is wrong in this structure?

Tags: grammaire

I encountered a question during an online test (the correct answer is b)), but I am curious why the answer a) is wrong, should be another article in front of "thé"? Or it is just a particular case I am not aware of?
And if I wanted to use beaucoup de/du thé, how this question should be reformulated: Chaque matin nous prenons beaucoup de thé?

**Chaque matin nous prenons … .
a) beaucoup du thé b) un verre de lait c) de la poisson**

Comment: See the question https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45443/question-on-usage-of-de-la-with-avec-and-beaucoup/45444#45444 and the answers therein. Hope it helps:-)!

Comment: Cela est dû à l'emploi de ***beaucoup** de* (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/beaucoup). Consultez le CNRTL, vous y trouverez beaucoup de tournures (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tournure 2b et 2a) idiomatiques usitées (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/usit%C3%A9) avec le mot qui vous intéresse, avec parfois la polysémie qui complique l'apprentissage de la langue.

Comment: But could you please explain why the answer a) is wrong here?

Comment: Lis tous les exemples du CNRTL et compare avec l'exemple … "astuce" : *beaucoup* induit une notion de *quantité*. Quand tu auras assimilé la structure de la phrase, tu pourras répondre à beaucoup d'autres QCM (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Questionnaire_%C3%A0_choix_multiples — tu peux copier le texte dans https://www.deepl.com/translator) qui traitent la notion de *quantité* : il n'y a pas de *plus, moins, …* avec "du/de la" après, ce qui n'est pas le cas lorsqu'il s'agit de la *qualité* : « Je bois *du* thé. »

Comment: …  Une langue ne s'apprend pas par les concepts grammaticaux, mais par les exemples (et les exceptions) et l'entraînement qui consiste à mettre ces exemples en pratique.

Comment: @Personne Bravo, finalement quelqu'un le dit!!

Comment: Il y a [beaucoup](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13872/when-to-use-de-or-des-after-nouns-and-after-beaucoup) [de](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13919/is-it-ever-okay-to-use-beaucoup-des?noredirect=1&lq=1) questions comme [ça](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14231/is-there-any-time-when-you-can-use-beaucoup-des?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 8):

The answer **a)** is not 100% wrong but it requires such an unlikely context that **b)** is necessarily the expected one; **c)** is obviously plain wrong because of a gender mismatch.

Another reason why **a)** is wrong is that it is very rare in France for someone to drink a lot of tea for the breakfast ;-)

Here is the kind of context that would make **a)** acceptable :

> *Chaque matin, nous prenons **beaucoup du thé** que tu nous a offert.* (see the ending note below)

As fierily discussed in other answers and comments, the expected form is:

> *Chaque matin, nous prenons beaucoup **de** thé*.

The best French Grammar book, *Le bon usage* (§ 626, a), states:

> La plupart des adverbes de degré employés comme déterminants indéfinis (***assez, beaucoup, combien, moins, plus, trop,*** etc.) sont unis au nom par ***de*** dans le français régulier.

i.e.

> Most adverbs of degree used as indefinite determiners (*assez, beaucoup, combien, moins, plus, trop,* etc.) are joined to the noun by *de* in regular French.

No explanation is given but a note states that in old French, these adverbs could also be followed by any of ***du***, ***de la*** or ***des***. Your question proves to be very legitimate: there is simply no obvious reason for ***de*** to be the current rule. You can't guess it, you have to know it.

In relaxed, regional or childish French, you might anyway ear:
(all examples from *Le Bon Usage*)

> *J'ai beaucoup **d'l**'argent dans ma poche.*

> *Il y a beaucoup **des** gens qui...*

> *On a quelquefois beaucoup **du** tourment dans notre métier (Alphone Daudet, Lettres de mon moulin)*

> *Ceux qui ont énormément **du** talent (Charles Péguy, Esprit du système)*

> *Ayant beaucoup **des** enfants, alors il se croit obligé d'aller en troisième (Raymond Queneau, Chiendent)*

Note also that there are plenty of cases where ***beaucoup*** can be legitimately followed by ***du thé*** without breaking any rule.

1. When it applies to a precise and determinate object:

> ***Beaucoup du thé** que nous buvons vient du Sri-Lanka.*

2. When the adverb *beaucoup* applies to the verb, not the object:

> *J'**aimerais beaucoup** du thé, s'il vous plait.*

> *Cette infusion a un goût qui se **rapproche beaucoup** du thé*.

Comment: It is 100% wrong in the OP's context. Also, you don't explain beaucoup de, so how does that help the OP really? Il se trouve que le matin je bois beaucoup de café. Et puis, boire du thé ou café, c'est un choix individuel. Je connais des français qui boivent du thé le matin....mais dire que c'est rare n'a rien à voir avec la grammaire ou le sens de la phrase.

Comment: @Lambie You misread my answer. I clearly wrote that the question context makes b) the only expected answer.  About whether my reply and my joke are useful or not to the OP and more generally to FSE users, let them decide.

Comment: Merci pour ces exemples avec *du* et surtout avec le *des* de ***Doukipudonktan*** maître de l'Olipo et des style[t]s de la francophonie … une sorte de père spirituel pour les adeptes de la créativité des oreilles et de la sérendipité des lectures. :-) :-) [humour francophile inaccessible à certains] :-) :-)

Answer (score 3):

The reason of this change is the so called "rule of erasement".

> ([ref.](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html)) L’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni massif s’efface aus­si après la pré­po­si­tion « de », par ex­em­ple dans la locu­tion ver­bale « avoir besoin de quel­que chose » :
>
> ♦ Il me faudrait   du  pain.
> ♦*<s>J’ai besoin de du pain.</s> →
>   J’ai besoin de   pain.

> ([Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-92176.php)) « Beaucoup de » qui exprime la grande quantité est assimilé à un adjectif ou un déterminant indéfini,
>
> il peut être remplacé par « bien du, de la, des »
>
> ♦ J'ai beaucoup de plaisir à t'écrire : j'ai bien du plaisir à t'écrire.

*Examples*

- J'ai **du** thé. (avoir quelque chose) — J'ai besoin **de** thé. (avoir besoin **de** quelque chose)
- Il y a **du** thé dans ce magasin. — Il y a toutes sortes **de** thé dans ce magasin.
- Elle a fait **du** pain. (*faire quelque chose*) — Un sandwich est fait **de** pain et souvent de viande. (faire quelque chose **de** quelque chose)

Here is one more reference showing those facts (and a little more).

> ([ref.](http://www.patenotte.name/Aix/Ecriture/Feuilles_aides_pedagogiques/articles_leur_suppression.html)) **3. La règle de la cacophonie : le problème avec *de de***
> L'article indéfini pluriel *des* et les partitifs *du/de la/des* disparaissent quand ils suivent la préposition *de*.
> Notez que les autres articles *le/la/les* et *un* et *une* restent quand ils suivent la préposition *de*.

The rule is also called the *rule of cacophony*.

Comment: erasement? Really? There is erasing and erasure pour effacement.

Comment: @Lambie It is rare nowadays: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/erasement

Comment: Pas flagrant comme explication avec *avoir* « — J'ai ***du*** thé. (avoir quelque chose) — J'ai ***le*** même thé (avoir quelque chose) [chez moi/au bureau/…] »

Comment: @Personne "J"ai le même thé." : ni partitif ni article  indefini ; c'est hors sujet.

Comment: « Ni partitif ni article indéfini » peut-être, mais ***du = de le*** … et on les trouve avec *avoir*, alors vos exemples ne sont pas audibles, i.e ne permettent pas de retrouver la construction intuitive des règles qui régissent soit *la quantité*, soit *la qualité* d'un produit/objet.

Comment: @Personne Justement, on le trouve avec «avoir » parce que ce verbe n'est pas construit avec la préposition « de »: on dit « _avoir qqc_ ». Mais avec la construction « _avoir besoin_ **de** », on ne le trouve plus, il est effacé, la cacophonie « besoin _de du_ thé » est éliminée. C'est tout, vraiment.

Answer (score 1):

***beaucoup de* is invariable in French. It does not take a "partitive" article.** With adverbs like beaucoup de and peu de is a preposition and not a partitive article. Therefore, what applies to them does not apply to these adverbs with the preposition de.

beaucoup de (meaning: a lot, much, or many, in translation) cannot take a partitive article. However, if there is a vowel as in the word argent (money) you can say beaucoup d'argent for a lot of money as de + a would be two vowels together.

So, it you want de say: **a lot of tea**, you have to say: **beaucoup de thé**.

Larousse:

> Beaucoup de, un grand nombre de, une grande quantité de : Il y a
> beaucoup de mécontents. Il reste beaucoup de travail à faire.

Please note, this is not the entire story about beaucoup and bien.

You can go to [this entry in the Larousse and read about the full story on these pronouns/adjectives/adverbs](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/beaucoup/8521)'

From another [French language teaching website](https://leflepourlescurieux.fr/exprimer-la-quantite-l-emploi-de-l-article-partitif-grammaire-a2/):

Exprimer la quantité:
Les adverbes beaucoup, peu, trop et assez apportent une précision sur le volume. Ils sont toujours suivis de la **préposition** de/d'/,

[bolding mine]

Comment: The reason is not the invariability of "beaucoup de" but the fact that "beaucoup de" is constructed with the preposition "de", and the rule is valid for all constructions with the préposition "de".  The preposition is the cause of not using "du"; it erases it so to speak. Didn't you understand the examples in my answer?

Comment: Sans oublier ***de*** pour *plus (sens ajout), moins, [un] peu,* … ou avec un verbe quantitatif : « je suis *saturé/en manque/ **de***, …»

Comment: @Lambie Here is another reference: "L'article indéfini pluriel des et les partitifs du/de la/des disparaissent quand ils suivent la préposition de.
Notez que les autres articles le/la/les et un et une restent quand ils suivent la préposition de. "http://www.patenotte.name/Aix/Ecriture/Feuilles_aides_pedagogiques/articles_leur_suppression.html

Comment: @LPH All I did was copy the Larousse entry. **beaucoup de**.  How can that be wrong?

Comment: @Lambie Il n'y a pas dans cette entrée une règle quelconque qui puisse justifier le fait que l'on ne traite plus l'idée de partie ; quand vous dites « besoin de thé » vous dites encore « besoin d'une partie de la masse que constitue tout le thé », seulement ce n'est plus signifié par l'article partitif, qui a été éliminé. La règle est que après la préposition  « de » il est éliminé. La raison ? Ça serait lourd, cacophonique en quelque sorte.